# Using declared variable in a range-based for-loop

Tags: c++

In the below example, `i` has function scope. But it seems that I cannot use `i` in the second for loop. Why does `for (i : v1)` not work, but `for (int i : v1)` works?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    int i;
    while(std::cin>>i)
    {
        v1.push_back(i);
    }

    for(i : v1) //for (int i:v1) works
        std::cout<<i<<"\t";
    cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NeilButterworth: actually, I can see how it can be surprising that range-based `for` requires a declaration rather than merely naming a variable. ... and I'd be surprised if typical textbooks cover the rational for this oddity.

Comment: @NeilButterworth  Unfortunately not

Comment: Check out the syntax for a range based for loop: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: Answer's because that's the way the language works, but I hope this question doesn't get locked. I bet the answer to why the language works this way is quite interesting.

Comment: @Dietmar. I must admit I had never thought that anyone would use a range-based loop in any other way - where would they have seen it being so used? I don't find it surprising textbooks don't explain the myriad ways _not_ to do things.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - I imagine it would be the same place where they see `int i;  for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` used. Not such a big leap to try that on a range-based for as well.

Comment: @Story Except for completely different syntax.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: actually, I don't think it is something you'd *see* somewhere. It could be seen as a logical use of range-based `for` and it is actually *illogical* that it is *not* supported! There is a reason but I think this reason may even be somewhat feeble...

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Syntax is immaterial. Your view may be skewed from your years of experience. To a novice, it may make perfect sense.

Comment: @Story Syntax is obviously very material, but that to the side, the worst things in my experience that learners can do is to start to invent their own syntax (or semantics) - many hours can be wasted this way. If you have a good textbook, write the code the way it is written in that textbook. If you are learning a language, you should probably put issues of language design on the back-burner.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: on the other hand, some things may be unnecessarily constrained and could benefit from making the language more regular, especially when it is made more general at the same time!

Comment: Let's turn the question upside-down and ask why you can use an existing variable in a traditional for loop, instead of having to declare one. Traditional for loops came from C from a time when all variables had to be declared at the top of a block, before any executable statement. The for-with-declaration syntax wasn't allowed at the time. The new range-based for statement is a new syntax and therefore there's no legacy code using it that the language needs to support. However, I agree that there's an argument for allowing pre-existing variables in the new syntax just to be consistent.

Comment: So this c++-specific question was closed as "too broad" by (among others) a Java programmer and an HTML/CSS/PHP/JavaScript guy. Shouldn't SO only allow you to vote if you've got a certain reputation in the specific field of the question?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a syntactical issue that a range-based `for` loop requires a *declaration of a named variable*, i.e. it requires a type specifier (cf, for  example, [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations)):

> for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
>
> range_declaration    -    a **declaration** of a named variable, whose type
>   is the type of the element of the sequence represented by
>   range_expression, or a reference to that type. Often uses the auto
>   specifier for automatic type deduction

Actually I don't know why your question got downvoted; I find your assumption quite OK; just the C++ syntax has decided to define it in  another way.

Answer (score 35):

The range-based `for` is specifically intended to replace loops akin to the following (this is a somewhat simplistic case; range-based `for`, especially the C++17 version, is more general than the example):

```
for (auto it = range.begin(), end = range.end(); it != end; ++it) {
   use(*it);
}
```

In the majority of cases won't use the values at the different locations but will rather use the element at the location itself:

1. When mutating the elements in the sequence a value doesn't really help.
2. In most cases copying the values is expensive and keeping a reference is more effective.
3. There are even cases where objects can't be copied to start with.

As a result the designers of range-based `for` decided that references absolutely have to be supported. At the same time, it was intended to use a reasonably simplistic rewrite-rule for a range-based `for`. The rule which is codified in the standard is this:

```
for (<range-decl>: <range>) { <body> }
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    auto&& range = <range>;        // keep the range alive!
    auto   it    = begin(range);   // actually, reality is bit more complicated
    auto   end   = end(range);     // actually, reality is a bit more complicated
    for (; it != end; ++it) {
        <range-decl> = *it;        // this is the rewrite causing your issue
        <body>
    }
}
```

In particular, the implication is that `<range-decl>` is a *declaration* rather than just naming a variable. The reason for this requirement is that typically the entity used in front of the `:` is a reference. However, references cannot be rebound. However, in each iteration of a loop a new reference can be used.

In principle the rewrite rule could work with using assignments if the `<range-decl>` isn’t a declaration but rather an lvalue. That would yield its own share of odd behaviors:

- There would be a difference between `for (T const& x: range)` and `T const& x = 0; for (x: range)`: the former works while the latter is an error.
- If the lvalue is a reference to an object located somewhere (`T& x = get_reference(); for (x: range) {...}`) the loop would automatically assign all the values in a range to an object located somewhere. Normally the objects are either located on the stack or in the source range (when the variable is declared as a reference).

It was consider more reasonable to only allow initialisations than supporting initialisation or assignments depending on how the variable is declared. Looking at the revision history of the proposals ([N2930](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2930.html) and predecessors) doesn’t yield a discussion but I vaguely recall that ths point was discussed.

Comment: This doesn't explain why `<range-decl>` couldn't be optionally a declaration or an lvalue. If we go by simple text replacement rule, this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Ruslan: fair comment. I have tried to address this point, too. I didn’t find a corresponding discussion in the papers (but I also didin’t look too closely) and I don’t think there were records at meetings kept at that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using range-based loops you need a declaration after opening parentheses, not only a variable. The correct syntax is:

```
 for ( declaration : range ) statement;
```

You can see [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/) for more information.

**In your example**: when you declare `i` before your `while` loop then you can use it in all of the `main` function and the scope of it is the `main` function. You can use it in that `for` body. When you are using the `i` variable in your `for` range then you aren't declaring it, because you already declared it above, so it will give you an error and it's not correct with C++ syntax.

But when you type `int` before the `i` in your `for` parenthesis then you are declaring another variable with the name of `i`, but only for your `for` loop and then it is OK with C++ syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is most likely because this would invoke **copy-assignments** on the variable, which would become a potential source of great inefficiency and in practice almost never be the intention... if the type supports copy-assignment at all.
So they probably figured it's best to prohibit this.